# Order files via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, rename

I have a main folder where other folders reside with .mkg files . These folders have a certain format.

Folder = NameSerie.SxEy.Randomstuf

Item in folder = NameSerie.SxEy.Randomstuf.mkv

Where x is the season number and y is the episode number.

What i want to do is automaticly create a folder if the nameSerie isnt already created and put the .mkv files in this folder.

So, if we have folders named NameSerie.SxEy.Randomstuf we check if folder NameSerie exists, if not we create one. Then we enter folder NameSerie.SxEy.Randomstuf and copy the NameSerie.SxEy.Randomstuf.mkv file in the NameSerie folder.

the file name needs to change from NameSerie.SxEy.Ra.n[dom}stuf.mkv to NameSerie.SxEy.mkv but I cant seem to figure out how to remove the random stuf after the NameSerie.SxEy.<   >.mkv

This is the code that i have managed to create but im still stuck. I have managed to create a folder if one does not exists but this only works if the .mkv file is not in a folder.

```
$Location = "\\<ip>\Share\Media\Series"

#rename files
Get-ChildItem $Location | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace(" [480p]","") }


#make folder for serie if it does not exist
Get-ChildItem "$Location\*.mkv" | 
Foreach-Object {

    $FullName = $_.Name
    $pos = $FullName.IndexOf(" - ")
    $Name = $FullName.Substring(0, $pos)

    Write-Host $_.FullName


    $TARGETDIR = "$Location\$Name"

    if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR ) )
    {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
    }

    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $TARGETDIR

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parameter `-Recurse` when you list files from the path like this:

`Get-ChildItem "$Location\*.mkv" -Recurse`

instead of:

`Get-ChildItem "$Location\*.mkv"`

With the -Recurse parameter, the script will list files in the current directory and for each directory in the current directory, it will do the same recursively. So the .mkv inside other folders won't hide any longer.